# how do I publish folder which contains 100 images over ROSTOPIC using custom message type

Tags: ros, image, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how to use folder which contains 100 images in custom message type..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141001/how-do-i-publish-folder-which-contains-100-images-over-rostopic-using-custom-message-type/) by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Write yourself a little publisher like:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <list>
#include <vector>

#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
      std::cout << "no image names given" << std::endl;
      return -1;
    }

  ros::init( argc, argv, "image_publisher" );
  
  ros::NodeHandle lo_nh;
  
  try
  {
    
    std::vector<cv::Mat> lv_images;
 
    ROS_INFO( "Loading images" );
    
    for ( int lo_i = 1; lo_i < argc; lo_i++ )
    {
      lv_images.push_back( cv::imread(std::string( argv[ lo_i ] ), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR ) );
    }
    
    ros::Publisher lo_pub = lo_nh.advertise<sensor_msgs/Image>( “/image”, 5 );
    
      int lo_rate = 10;
      
      ROS_INFO_STREAM( "Publishing images at " << lo_rate << "hz" );
      ros::Rate lo_rate1( lo_rate );
      
      std::vector<cv::Mat>::iterator lo_iter_imgs( lv_images.begin() ), lo_iter_imgs_end( lv_images.end() );
      
      for ( ; lo_iter_imgs != lo_iter_imgs_end ; ++lo_iter_imgs )
      {
    cv_bridge::CvImage lo_img;
    lo_img.encoding = "bgr8";
    lo_img.image = *lo_iter_imgs;   
    
    lo_pub.publish(lo_img.toImageMsg() );
    
    ros::spinOnce();
    lo_rate1.sleep();
      }
      
  }
  catch ( const std::exception& lo_e )
  {
    std::cout << "Exception in main: " << lo_e.what() << std::endl;
    
    return -1;
  }
  catch( ... )
  {
    std::cout << "Unknown exception in main" << std::endl;
    
    return -1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

And call it with all images in the current folder using a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Working ..."

FILES= 

for i in $(ls *.png); do
 FILES="${FILES} ${i}"
done

rosrun my_pkg my_image_publisher $FILES

echo "Done"
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1